# Could not acquire a semaphore for execution and fallback failed Exception

Tags: rx-java, hystrix

We have Two backend services Say Service A and Service B.

service A returns list of ids and for each id we make call to Service B. We have created one HystrixObservableCommand for service A and one HystrixObservableCommand for each id returned by service A.

Is this the right approach?

How to set ThreadPoolSize for each command?

When we are using Hystrix do we need to use subscribeOn() and ObserveOn() for RxJava Observable?

Currently i am getting could not acquire a semaphore for execution and fallback failed Exception in service B.